# scrollTop after form submits

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm using a BootStrap theme in which I have a form at the bottom of page. When submitted and the page reloads, I'm presented page top and thus the form is undesirably off-screen.

## HTML Anchor

Using a HTML anchor in the action attribute of the form does not work because certain images take longer to load than it takes the browser to jump to the anchor so I end up further up the page than I should.

## jQuery scrollTop

I've opted for using jQuery scrollTop however when I place it within the submit event, the page loads and the scroll does not occur. How can achieve scrollTop after form submission?`

## Code

```
$( window ).load(function() {   
    $("#someform").submit(function(){           
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#someid").offset().top
        }, 2000);   
    });
});
```

Comment: I've already reviewed similar questions on stackoverflow but they relate the iframes or ajax.

Comment: _“because certain images take longer to load than it takes the browser to jump to the anchor so I end up further up the page than I should”_ – specify image dimensions then (either via `width`/`height` HTML attribute, or via CSS), so that the browser knows how much space to reserve for them beforehand already. That has been considered good practice since basically forever already. (And yes, this is possible for “responsive” images as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#someform").submit(function(e){           
        e.preventDefault();
        var submitForm = $(e.target);
        $.ajax({
            url: submitForm.attr("action"),
            data: submitForm.serialize(),
            method: submitForm.attr("method"),
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Form submitted: " + data);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: No effect. I remain page top though the form submits as expected.

Comment: The form is not submitting on my end :-(

Comment: Actually, I just realized the reason why you want to scroll. The form is submitting, its just not displayable because its being done though AJAX and I assume the element you're scrolling to is at the top of the form? Let me fix that

Comment: Using AJAX removes the page reload all together.

Comment: AJAX seems to be the way to go but I'm having difficulty understanding how incorporate "data" with my PHP mail function. I'll work it out using this tutorial: http://spruce.it/noise/simple-ajax-contact-form/. Incidentally, "data" outputs the entire page's source code. Not sure if this is meant to be the case. I figured out an alternative by passing a variable via the URL if you're curious: http://pastebin.com/KKN58CBF